# Difference in IP address formats

Tags: ip, ip-address

I asked a client to send me the ip address of all of their locations so that I could block them from analytics.

Most of them are what I know as normal: 0.00.000.000

but some of them are coming to be kind of like this: 2001:500:f000:100:7000:40d0:3000:400c

They are all going to google and typing "whats my ip address" and sending me the results. Is the second example an ip address I can exclude? do I need to convert it some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are IPv6 addresses. What you're looking at inside the usual xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format is IPv4.

These two formats of addressing are entirely incompatible with one another. They cannot be "converted", however when dealing with application layer systems they should/usually work in almost the exact same way. i.e. if you were to ban an IPv6 address, it would work in the same way as banning an IPv4.

There's a plethora of documentation available online about IPv6, and it's probably a bit out of scope for this site, so I hope that helps you figure it all out! Even if it is just a single piece of your puzzle :)

Comment: Wow, thanks I had no idea there were different types of IP address. unfortunately I tried entering the IPv6 address and I get an error saying the format needs to be IPv4 so in this case they aren't interchangeable. I'm checking to see if it is an issue with Hubspot, the service I am trying to block the ip's in.

Comment: Blocking an IPv6 address is probably rather useless anyway, since they're largely ephemeral.

Comment: @deceze  -that's true. I think our IPv6 range gives us like 1.2*10^24 ipv6 addresses. But he can look up the CIDR of the user and ban the range